# Django: Access Model fields in template when using form.ModelMultipleChoiceField

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

It is a follow up to this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41575870/django-check-multiple-choices-with-not-fixed-choices). My question now is, when I have a ModelMultipleChoiceField in my form how do I access all of the model fields of a passed queryset in template?

Currently my form is:

```
class CarChoicesForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        cars = kwargs.pop('cars', None)
        super(CarChoicesForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['cars']=forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=cars,
                                                            widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
```

Template:

```
<tbody>
{% for choice in form.cars %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ choice.choice_label }}</td>
        <td><span class="checkbox">{{ choice.tag }}</span></td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

It only prints what `Car.__str__()` provides, but I need other fields to achieve something like [this](https://postimg.org/image/trj07ajgj/). I tried `{{ choice.choice_label.brand }}`, etc. with no success.

Comment: Sounds like y'all need to create a custom widget for this (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/widgets/#customizing-widget-instances). Have you explored this option?

Comment: I went through Django code for both the `forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple` and `forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField`. If I understood correctly, choices are generated in `ModelMultipleChoiceField` as tuples of tag and label. Label is obtained from method `label_from_instance(obj)` as a string. I tried to override that method and leave the whole obj as is, but without success. Widget works with choices and not queryset, so if choices are generated in `ModelMultipleChoiceField` in such a way, I don't see how can I solve my problem through widgets.

Comment: I am still a beginner in Django, so I'll try to dig up some more, but this is what I concluded for now.